# Check NSApp on Cocoa/OSX app has modal mode

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsapplication

How to check NSApp has modal mode?

Stop modal window

```
[NSApp stopModal];
```

But I don't see property check current app state is modal or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check property modalWindow on NSApp

```
BOOL isModalMode = !![NSApp modalWindow];
```